# Hyperlinks in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, sharepoint

I have an Excel 2013/Office 365 spreadsheet stored in a SharePoint Library. It contains hyperlinks created using the "Place In This Document" functionality - not a hyperlink formula. The links are all to a cell in another tab within the same workbook.

Prior upgrading to Excel 2013, the screentip would read [Name of the tab]A4. Now the hyperlink screentip shows the full address of the file and there is a a few seconds long pause when clicking the link.

Does anyone know if this is a change in functionality from 2010 to 2013/Office 365?

Comment: The delay might be due to Excel trying resolve the full path

Comment: Of course it is. I am trying to figure out why it is using a full path.